# What is the best way to write data via MVC into database?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am working on a homework project using MVC with EF Core.
I am looking for the best way to write data into the database. (I am beginner)
There are two tables. `Predbilježba`(Enrollment) and `Seminari`(Seminars)

```
public class Predbilježba
{
    [Key]
    public int PredbilježbeID { get; set; }
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public string Prezime { get; set; }
    public string Adresa { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DatumUpisa { get; set; }  
    public int SeminarID { get; set; }
    public Seminar Seminar { get; set; }
}

public class Seminar
{
    public int SeminarID { get; set; }
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
    public string Opis { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public bool Popunjen { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Predbilježba> Predbilježba { get; set; }
}
```

I need to insert a sort of Enrollment (Named: `Predbilježba`) into the database.
Enrollment is connected to a table called Seminars (Named: `Seminari`).

So when a person is "enrolling" into a "seminar", he/she needs to insert basic data into form (name, phone number, etc.) and they need to choose a "seminar" from a list of given seminars which are in "Seminar" table.

So when they click "Save", their basic data is written into `Predbilježba` / (eng. Enrollment)" along with chosen "seminar"

So I already have controllers for these 2 models, and appropriate views to create, edit, and so on..

My question is: Do I create a separate controller/model/view to insert data into tables? Can someone give me some example of how it is done?

To clarify further, I need to make user side page where user can "enroll" to "seminar" by writing name, last name, etc.. and by choosing the desired seminar. For now I have functional database, Identity (which will be used later in project), controllers of both models, and appropriate views where I can edit `Prebilježbe`(eng. Enrollments) and Seminars.

Images of page follow:
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]
[image: Image4]

So when user clicks Upiši se (eng. enroll) as shown in image number 3. , that selected Seminar, along with basic info that opens after the click (image 4 ) needs to be written into database "Predbilježbe" (eng Enrollments)

This "Upis" page would be a user input page, and "Seminari" and "Predbilježbe" would be admin pages..

Comment: What do you mean with 'insert data into tables'? if you have already created two controllers for each entity, you are good to go. Can you clarify better what you wanto to achieve?

Comment: Please consider to read the documentation of mvc core, they have a lot of examples there and you can take advantage from them. There are too many ways to accomplish what you want and choosing one will depend on the architecture you choosed  to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about good architectural design. Aren't you? (if not please let me know to edit the answer).

You have many architectural choices and possibilities. The easiest one for you to start with is the Service-Repository architectural pattern. I would omit the Repository word here because EF is already (in my opinion) a Repository pattern implementation (at least partially).

So to keep it simple, you would like to start with **Service architectural pattern**. Which is about creating a class, which injects the `DbContext` in its construction (let's name it `PredbilježbaService`). And in this class, you handle all operations of your logic (including database EF queries).

Then you inject this class to your controller and call the required functions from that service class (which deals with the database) in your controller.

The same process can be applied to the other entity `Seminar`.

P.S. by injecting I mean using any IoC design pattern (in ASP.Net Core, dependency injection is already built-in).

So after these brief words, **to answer your question** directly, **yes**, a good software design would be by creating a separate class which handles database operations (adding rows, editing rows, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what your application is supposed to do.

If this is nothing more than a few views around a few tables, then it is perfectly fine to save these objects directly from the controller. The best design is usually the simplest one and there is no need to overcomplicate things with layers, architectural patterns and so on. These are relevant when the size of the project is much larger than in your case.

Good design is all about communication. If someone else is supposed to maintain your project, will it be clear to them where to find the functionality?

I would expect two controllers: one for seminars (called SeminarController) and one for enrollments (called EnrollmentController). These will have methods for viewing, inserting, modifying and deleting data. I would be able to extend your project easily because I know where (and how) to find the code. So your suggestion seems like a good fit.

---

**Response to comment**

In the list of seminars has a link pointing to the screen where someone can register for a seminar. That action needs to know which seminar has been selected. The way to do it is to pass the id of the seminar with the request, e.g. `/Enrollment/Register/{seminar id}`. This results in a GET-request. The form in the enrollment view will POST the inputted data back to the controller.

In the `EnrollmentController` you would have something like this:

```
private readonly MyDbContext context;

// Constructor and other methods omitted

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register(int seminarId)
{
    var seminar = context.Seminars.Single(x => x.Id == seminarId);
    return View(seminar);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Enrollment enrollment)
{
    context.Enrollment.Add(enrollment);
    return RedirectToAction("index", "Seminar");
}
```

Depending on the requirements, you might need to insert some validation etc.

Comment: Understood, but I am a little bit stuck..

If you can see the uploaded images of the page, in image 3 and 4 is the main problem..
How can I select seminar (image 3) and than, when redirected to page on image 4, where I input basic data (name, etc..), the seminar choice and info data get saved in database?
What is the code behind that function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to study about software architectures a bit to clarify this. Try reading about [Layered Architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch01.html) for basic structures, and I am assuming you already understand how the [MVC architecture](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/basic_mvc_architecture.htm) works. These will clarify where to perform which task. One of my favorites is the [Onion architecture](https://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/understanding-onion-architecture). So basically when you implement an architecture in your code, it becomes much more easy to read, control and track all activities performed within the code.

At the simplest, it is better to split the tasks as below:

```
1. You define your model classes 
2. You create a database class/layer, where you will implement the logic to perform data base queries into your database with respect to the models and return the formatted data (This is where you perform the EF core queries).
3. You create your controllers, where you handle tasks by sending appropriate requests to the database layer and fetch the formatted data.
4. You create your views based on the expected model, and setup the controllers to send the formatted model data to the appropriate view.
```

A good place to start is here: [Tutorial on EF core with MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve this in MVC is tu use the nuget package  [EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Here is a step by step documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/

For any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: The author is stating the project is using 'EF Core', So mentioning the existence of Entity Framework is not very helpful. (To be fair, the question isn't either)