# Saving View generated variables to my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, variables, razor

I am creating an MVC application and do not want to use external Libraries. I need to populate a specific week with the related dates and this will change weekly, I want to then save the date with the relevant person and project information for that date to my database. I believe i need to give an Id to the relevant table tag, but I do not know how to do this. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

I have created the Models and auto generated the Controllers and views, I am still editing the Views and realized that I have this problem. I have figured out how to populate the days for the specific week, but do not know how to implement it in MVC.

```
        var currentWeek = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var newWeek = GetDateFromWeekNumberAndDayOfWeek(currentWeek);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            var weekDays = newWeek.AddDays(i);
            if (weekDays.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && weekDays.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Day " + (i + 1) + " " + weekDays.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static DateTime GetDateFromWeekNumberAndDayOfWeek(int weekNumber)
    {
        DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
        int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;
        // Use first Thursday in January to get first week of the year as it will never be in Week 52/53
        DateTime firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);

        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

        var weekNum = weekNumber;
        // As we're adding days to a date in Week 1, we need to subtract 1 in order to get the right date for week #1
        if (firstWeek <= 1)
        {
            weekNum -= 1;
        }
        // Using the first Thursday as starting week ensures that we are starting in the right year then we add number of weeks multiplied with days
        var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);
        // Subtract 3 days from Thursday to get Monday, which is the first weekday in ISO8601
        //addition use -4 to get Sunday as first day
        return result.AddDays(-4);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please specify what is your exact problem?

Comment: I dont have a specific problem, I just do not know where to look how to save dates generated in my view to a variable/property in my model.

Comment: How are you posting the Person and Project values to your controller? If you show me your view, I can help you.

Comment: So is your problem specific to the dates? or is it a general problem about saving data in the database? Take a look at my answer in the following question, does this  help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809904/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-data-via-mvc-into-database/55810279#55810279

Comment: I am using DB Context and the lambda expression to bind it and save to the database. but I do not know the process of how to implement my code above to display those dates in my view and then save a specific day to the database. I will attempt to finish my view and then post it, I might have been premature in my question.